# Subst in a list

Tags: maxima

I will give an example to explain my problem: I have a list in the form `list1:[x*y*z,x*z,y]`. Now I have another list, `list2:[1,2,3]`. What I'm trying to do is substitute the value `list2[1]`, i.e. 1, into the x variable of my `list1`, the value `list2[2]` into the y variable of my `list1`, and so on. The output should be   `[1*2*3,1*3,2]` or `[6,3,2]`. Note that both lists have the same length.

What I tried to do is:

```
list3:for i:1 thru length(list2) do (subst(list2[i],list1[i])
```

But it didn't work. How can I do this?

Thanks in advance,

Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(%i1) list1: [x*y*z,x*z,y] $
(%i2) kk: ['x, 'y, 'z] $
(%i3) vv: [ 1,  2,  3] $
(%i4) sl: maplist(lambda([k, v], k = v), kk, vv) $
(%i5) subst(sl, list1);
(%o5)                              [6, 3, 2]
```